Twitter Login error obtaining user auth token
[[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion:^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
            
            if (session) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self presentViewController:composer animated:YES completion:nil];
                });
            } else {
                [self showAlertWithMessage:@"You must log in before presenting a composer." andTitle:@"No Twitter Accounts Available"];
            }
}];

trying to login to twitter to share image.
My Twitter ConsumerKey and ConsumerSecret both are correct and valid And the redirect url in developer portal is also according to guidelines like twitterkit-consumerkey://.
But I am unable to login and get the session details. The error shown is:
[TWTRURLSessionDelegate] Cancelling API request, SSL certificate is invalid.
[TwitterKit] Cannot verify session credentials.
[TWTRURLSessionDelegate] Cancelling API request, SSL certificate is invalid.
[TwitterKit] Error obtaining user auth token.
Error code is: -999(cancelled)
It is redirect back to app saying the above error details.
Any kind of lead or help is highly appreciated.
